# "roof" over numbers

Tags: music

[image: "roof" over numbers]

I'm writing a musicology paper and need some roman/schenkerian analysis tools. Notice the image, the "roof" over the numbers? How to produce this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You get such a “roof” with `\hat`:

```
$\sharp\hat{4}$
```

There's also `\widehat` for – well – wider objects:

```
$\widehat{11}$
```

Both are mathaccents and therefore need to be used in math mode.

Comment: One probably should define a semantic macro here but since I don't know the meaning of the hat in said musical context I didn't post an example...